# How to track the index of all seleted cells in UITableView

Tags: iphone

I have a `UITableView` with about 20 rows. I also use check mark accessory to identify the selected. The problem I face now is that the selection gets messed up when I scroll (here  I am selecting multiple rows). So after scroll the selected `checkmark` has vanished.  Can anyone help me to find a way? in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`

```
NSMutableDictionary *rowDict = [tableList objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

if([tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark)
{

    [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

}
else
{
    [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;

    checkedIndexPath =  indexPath;

    NSLog(@"the checked psths are :%@",checkedIndexPath);

}
```

And in `cellforrowatIndexpath` I use

```
if([self.checkedIndexPath isEqual:indexPath])
{
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
}
else 
{
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
}
```

But this works only for single selection.  What should I do for multiple selection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have an `NSMutableArray` which can add `n` number of `NSIndexPath`s corresponding to the cells selected. When a cell is deselected, you can remove that indexpath from the array.

Comment: so you say to do this  didSelectRowAtIndexPath and then match the array in cellForRowAtIndexPath to check or uncheck the creating cell right?

Answer (score 0):

You should use an array to store checked indices. If you use a single property then only the last selected row will get the correct accessoryType.

Answer (score 0):

I used this code many times (With some minor changes as required)

```
  - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:
                (NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
    {

       UITableViewCell *thisCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];


        if (thisCell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone) 
        {
          thisCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        }
      else
       {
          thisCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        }
    }

   - (UITableViewCellAccessoryType)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
             accessoryTypeForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
     {
        //add your own code to set the cell accesory type.
               return UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
      }
```